# Cannot update multiple tables though no error occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following parent class which has multiple child classes. I have successfully created and  retrieved data from SQL database. Now I want to update record by using `FormCollection`.

```
public class UserDetailContext : DbContext
{
    public UserDetailContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserDetails> UserDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonalDetails> PersonalDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HoroscopeDetails> HoroscopeDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Expectations> Expectations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FamilyDetails> FamilyDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AddressDetails> AddressDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EducationalDetails> EducationalDetails { get; set; }
}    

public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List <PersonalDetails>  PdetailsList { get; set; }
    public List<HoroscopeDetails> HDetailsList { get; set; }
    public List<EducationalDetails> EDetailsList { get; set; }

    public List<AddressDetails> AdddetailsList { get; set; }
    public List<FamilyDetails> FDetailsList { get; set; }
    public List<Expectations> ExpDetailsList { get; set; }

    public PersonalDetails Pdetails { get; set; }
    public HoroscopeDetails  HDetails { get; set; }
    public EducationalDetails  EDetails { get; set; }
    public AddressDetails Adddetails { get; set; }
    public FamilyDetails FDetails { get; set; }
    public Expectations ExpDetails { get; set; }
    public UserDetails()
    {
        Pdetails = new PersonalDetails();
        HDetails = new HoroscopeDetails();
        EDetails = new EducationalDetails();

        Adddetails = new AddressDetails();
        FDetails = new FamilyDetails();
        ExpDetails = new Expectations();
    }   
}

public class PersonalDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int PersonalID { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string RegID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MidName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }


}

public class HoroscopeDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Rashi { get; set; }
    public int PersonalID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonalID")]
    public virtual PersonalDetails Product { get; set; }
}

public class EducationalDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int EduID { get; set; }
    public string EducationDetails { get; set; }
    public string Education { get; set; }
    public int PersonalID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonalID")]
    public virtual PersonalDetails Product { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AddId { get; set; }               

    public int PersonalID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonalID")]
    public virtual PersonalDetails Product { get; set; }
}

public class FamilyDetails
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FId { get; set; }


    public int PersonalID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonalID")]
    public virtual PersonalDetails Product { get; set; }
}

public class Expectations
{           
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ExpId { get; set; }
    public int PersonalID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonalID")]
    public virtual PersonalDetails Product { get; set; }
}
```

Now from controller I want to update a record

```
public void UpdateRecord(FormCollection coll)
{      
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
    UserDetails obj = db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserId.Equals(id));
    obj.Pdetails.FirstName = "xxxx";
    obj.Pdetails.LastName = "xxxx";
    obj.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);
    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    int result = db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It doesn't give any error but also doesn't update any record.
And `obj` object also contains null values by following code:

```
UserDetails obj = db.UserDetails.FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserId.Equals(id));
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault returns exactly what it says, the first record or the default. In your case I suspect there is no record it can find matching the id you're specifying so there is no record to update.

You have to make sure that it finds a record before you can update it.

Comment: I don't know how MVC handles the exception when obj.Pdetails.FirstName = "xxxx" is called? You should get a Null Reference Exception then...

Comment: it fetches records with userId but other details are null like pdetails,hdetails,FDetails etc